# Function after each in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, append, each

I want to make a function after each image has been appended in the code below. It should wait until all images have been appended and loaded.

I hope you understand...

```
$('#some_id').click(function () {
    $('.some_images').each(function () {
        $('#some_container').append('<img style="display:none;margin:auto;" class="some_class" src="' + $(this).attr("src").replace(/\.(gif|png|jpg)$/, '-big.$1') + '" />');
    });
});

if(allImagesAreLoaded){alert('done');}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to write it yourself, someone has already done it for you.

[ImagesLoaded jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)